# PHP make array go back to 0 when reached last item

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array with 6 different colors in it like this:

```
$colors = array(
        'dd0330',
        'e49fca',
        'a776a6',
        'f7e300',
        'f78f1e',
        'd12a2f',
);
```

And I have a loop where I store some stuff in an array, I add for every element a color. But the array can have more items than 6 so when the sixth color is being gifted out I want the counter to be reset

This is what I've tried:

```
$loop_counter = 0;
if ( $orders->have_posts() ){
   while ($orders->have_posts()) : $orders->the_post(); 
      ...
      $myOrders[] = array( 'name' => $name,
                                 'schedule' => $activiteiten, 
                                 'link' => $link, 
                                 'color' => $colors[$loop_counter],
                                 'catering' => $catering,
                               ); 
       ...
       if($loop_counter = 5){
           $loop_counter = 0;
       }
       $loop_counter++;
    endwhile; 
}
```

But this seems to give my first item the first color and everythin else the second one.

Anyone know how I can reset my counter?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use double == in condition eg: if($loop_counter == 5).

Comment: using "endwhile;" looks so ugly... Why don't you use `{ }` ?

Answer (score 10):

So close!

Try

```
if($loop_counter == 5)
```

You need an equivalence relation, not an equals

Also, if you're going to have your $loop_counter++ after the if, your if should set $loop_counter = -1.

Comment: Wauw I feel so stupid about the `==` haha. I have placed my `$loop_counter++` above my if so we all good! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do better.

```
$myOrders[] = array( 'name' => $name,
                             'schedule' => $activiteiten, 
                             'link' => $link, 
                             'color' => $colors[$loop_counter % 6],
                             'catering' => $catering,
                           );
```

`%` gives you a remainder, and you never have to check and reset the counter.

If the number of colors can be changed, use

```
$colors_num = count($colors);
// ...
                            'color' => $colors[$loop_counter % $colors_num],
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding the max value into your if statement, you can create an `ArrayIterator`, e.g.

```
$it = new ArrayIterator($colors);
if ( $orders->have_posts() ){
   while ($orders->have_posts()) : $orders->the_post(); 
      //...
      if(!$it->valid()){
          $it->rewind();
      }
      $myOrders[] = array( 'name' => $name,
                                 'schedule' => $activiteiten, 
                                 'link' => $link, 
                                 'color' => $it->current(),
                                 'catering' => $catering,
                               ); 
       //...
       $it->next();
    endwhile; 
}
```

Comment: This works too, and is a lot cleaner. But the amount of colors is fixed. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

```
     $loop_counter++;
 if($loop_counter == 6){
               $loop_counter = 0;
           }
```

can try this

Answer (score 1):

PHP array function [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is dedicated for this purpose.

```
if ($loop_counter == 6) {
 reset($colors);
}
```

This will reset your array pointer to first element.